# java copy constructor in different package

Tags: java, inheritance, package, copy-constructor

I want to create a copy constructor in a different package. How can I go around this? Here is what I have. The Festival Class extends the Event class. I know I must use the super() but I do not know what to put inside. Could someone help me understand further?

```
public class Event {

private int year;
private int month;
private int numOfCities;

    public Event() {

       year = 0;
       month = 0;
       numOfCities = 0;

    }

public class Fair extends Event{

   private int numOfExib;
   private String exibType;

   public Fair() {

       super(0, 0, 0);
       numOfExib = 0;
       exibType = "";

   }

   public Fair(Fair anotherFair) {

       super(0,0,0); //I don't know what to put in here!
       numOfExib = anotherFair.numOfExib;
       exibType = anotherFair.exibType;

}
```

Comment: Your `Event` constructor takes no arguments...

Comment: *I want to create a copy constructor in a different package* The statement doesn't make any sense. A constructor belongs to a class, so it cannot be declared outside of the class. Thinking to create a constructor in a different package just defies how Java is designed.

Comment: Rollback: please, do not incomporate the answer in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a copy constructor for `Event`:

```
public class Event {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int numOfCities;

    /** default constructor */
    public Event() {
        year = month = numOfCities = 0; // unnecessary, as 0 is the default value
    }

    /** copy constructor */
    public Event(Event other) {
        year = other.year;
        month = other.month;
        numOfCities = other.numOfCities
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in the subclass:

```
public class Fair extends Event {
    private int numOfExib;
    private String exibType;

    /** default constructor */
    public Fair() {
        // no need to explicitly call default constructor
        numOfExib = 0; // unnecessary, but I like to explicitly initialize
        exibType = ""; // this is necessary to avoid a null value
    }

    /** copy constructor */
    public Fair(Fair other) {
        super(other); // parent class's copy constructor
        numOfExib = other.numOfExib;
        exibType = other.exibType;
    }
    ...
}
```

By creating a copy constructor for `Event`, you decouple the internals of `Event` from its subclass(es). The copy constructor for a subclass just needs to pass up the object to be copied to `Event` and the copy constructor for `Event` handles its own copy logic internally.

P.S.

I note that your posted code invokes an `Event` constructor that doesn't exist in your posted code—one that takes three `int` arguments (presumably the year, month, and number of cities for the event). If you added that constructor to the base class, you then probably would want to add constructors to the `Fair` class to also pass in explicit values. Since the `Fair` class also includes two more fields, you would then end up needing a five-argument constructor. Whenever you start seeing long constructors like that, it's usually advisable to switch to a builder pattern. (A web search will turn up lots of tutorials about this pattern in Java. It's quite easy to implement.)

A builder pattern also addresses the problem of potential confusion about argument order, a particular danger when many of the arguments have the same data type. For instance, is `new Event(0, 0, 0)` passing the year, month, and number of days in that order? Or is it month, year, days? Or something else? With a builder pattern, you don't have that ambiguity. The idea is to end up with classes that you would use something like this:

```
Fair.Builder builder = new Fair.Builder();
builder.setYear(2018)
        .setMonth(7)
       // etc.
       .setExibType("recruitment");
Fair fair = builder.build();
```

To accomplish this, `Event` would have a static nested builder class (usually called `Builder`, but the name is not important) and `Fair` would also have a static nested builder class that extends `Event.Builder`.

Comment: @Mohanad - It compiles fine for me. What error message(s) are you getting from the compiler?

Comment: Did you put them in different packages? I am required to do so.

Comment: @Mohanad - I didn't put them in different packages. But that shouldn't matter as long as you have the correct `import` statement in the subclass and the correct access specifier (`public`) in the base class. The parent's constructor(s) need to be `public` or `protected`. They can't be `private` or package-private (default). Again, what is the specific error message the compiler is generating? That will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: It says "The constructor Event(Festival) is undefined"

Comment: @Mohanad - Is `Festival` a subclass of `Event`? Did you add a copy constructor to the `Event` class itself?

Comment: @Mohanad - You're edited code is a bit confusing because `Fair` still has a call to `super(0,0,0)`, which doesn't match any constructor in `Event`. Also, the braces are mismatched, so it looks like `Fair` is an inner class of `Event`, yet you say it's in another package. Also, the error message is for `Festival`, not `Fair`. (P.S. I just tested my suggested code split into two packages and it still compiles just fine, as expected.)

Comment: @Mohanad - Ah. In `Fair`, you're importing the wrong `Event` class. You need to import `Event.Event`, not `java.awt.Event`. (By the way, by convention, Java package names should be all lower case.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 super(0, 0, 0);
```

This would throw an error. Your event constructor should have this:

```
public Event(int year, int month, int numberOfCities)
```

The fair, too. If you want to use the constructor of the `super` class, your `child` class constructor should *contain the same number of arguments* as the super. Though there are cases like this

```
public Fair(String name){
super(1, 3, 5);
// ^^These are "default values" saying that the event will always contain these values whenever you create a Fair instance
this.name = name;
}
```

The example above isn't copying the constructor. Copying the constructor would be as simple as this

```
public Fair(int year, int month, int numberOfCities){
super(year, month, numberOfCities);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost done, just add a copy-constructor in the parent:

```
public class Event {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int numOfCities;

    public Event() {
      // by default all int fields are 0;
    }

    // This is a copy-constructor
    public Event(final Event otherEvent) {
       year = otherEvent.year;
       month = otherEvent.month;
       numOfCities = otherEvent.numOfCities;
    }
}

public class Fair extends Event {
   private int numOfExib;
   private String exibType;

   public Fair() {
       exibType = "";
   }

   public Fair(Fair anotherFair) {
       super(anotherFair); //Pass the given object to the super constructor

       numOfExib = anotherFair.numOfExib;
       exibType = anotherFair.exibType;
   }
}
```